# What should you call a Mori Dream Space (or surface) in Spanish?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, translation

(My apologies if this turns out to be judged to be not appropriate for MathOverflow - I thought about it twice, but then I am nearly certain that I would be much less likely to get an answer there!)

"Mori dream surface" and "Mori dream spaces" are standard terms. Now, I am co-organizing a summer school in Spanish, with algebraic geometry as one of the topics. There has been some discussion as to what to call a "Mori dream surface". One could leave it untranslated, but mostly "Superficies Mori dream" simply does not look right.

I would say "superficies de ensueño de Mori" (rather than "sueño"), but then, while I am a native speaker of Spanish, I am no algebraic geometer. What do algebraic geometers (and/or other fluent speakers) suggest?

Comment: I have heard the expression "espacios de ensueño de Mori",  and in particular, "superficies de ensueño de Mori", as you mention.

Comment: @FZaldivar Do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't know Spanish at all but should not this be some kind of adjective? Like soñador or something?

Comment: "Soñador" is a noun, meaning "dreamer".

Comment: @H A Helfgott: I don't have a reference: I heard it at a conference by one of my colleagues that works in birational geometry.

Comment: I do not think it is correct to leave it untranslated if the seminar is mainly in spanish and for spanish speaking people. According to wikipedia "the notion is named so because it behaves nicely from the point of view of Mori's minimal model program". So, "espacios de ensueño de Mori" works great, and also "espacio de ensoñación de Mori". Perhaps "espacio soñado de Mori" also works, although it is not literal (and at least in Chile saying that something ideal is "soñado/a" is a bit cringy).